# MATLAB GUI axes getting changed

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Currently I'am working on MATLAB GUI. In this GUI I have two axes and three push buttons. Now the problem is whenever I add another element in the GUI or move anything in GUI the 'Tag' and the 'Create Function' of the property inspector gets changed, due to which the axes part of the GUI stops working and it had to be initialize again.

Comment: seems strange to me: what matlab version are you using?

Comment: I'am using MATLAB R2010